# Check the spring-data-jpa version in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

As in question the [pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/pom.xml) from started does not provide the version information

Answer (score 4):

Using dependency tree we can see versions of all dependencies in the maven project.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

Comment: Its downloading all the dependencies. I lost my precious time. Though its showing the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the maven dependencies folder in the project explorer of the IDE.

The version number is present at the end of the file name, like

`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar`

Here **2.5.5** is the version number of the corresponding file.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can find the version.

1. One option is to verify the version downloaded from you IDE or from you .m2 folder
2. If you want to know where the version is specified you need to travel through the `<parent>` tag mentioned in the pom.xml. In the case of Spring Boot Data JPA Starter pom.xml the version is specified in spring-boot-build pom.xml within the properties tag. You can check the below link for the pom.xml definition :

[spring-boot-build pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/pom.xml)